# Javascript - Remove/Detach Timestamp from log file

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, split

I currently have a pretty big log file where the lines look like this

```
2013-10-08 22:58:38 [INFO] [more info] Description or command
```

I would like to know how to split it at this point

```
2013-10-08 22:58:38 | [INFO] [more info] Description or command
```

Right after the date so that i can put them into a different style

```
<div class="console-line"><span class="Datetime">2013-10-08 22:58:38</span>[INFO] [more info] Description or command</div
```

I know how to split the text at that exact point, but the problem is that not all lines actually have a timestamp

Comment: Can you say what the other lines look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the line at the first index of '[':

```
var index = line.indexOf('[');
line = '<div...>' + line.substring(0, index) + '</span>' + 
           line.substring(index) + '</div>'
```

Comment: You forgot to open the <span> ^^ 

That should work for the most part, but what happens if there are no brackets in a line?

Comment: What about this ?
`if (line.indexOf('[') > -1) {
line = '<div...>' + line.substring(0, index) + '</span>' + 
           line.substring(index) + '</div>' }
else {
line = '<div...>' + line + '</div>';`

Answer (score 0):

Use a RegEx to find the timestamps.

I wrote this: `/^(\d{4}(?:\-\d{2}){2}\s\d{2}(?:\:\d{2}){2})(.*)/`, that matches two groups: the timestamp, and the rest of the line.

[Code here](http://jsbin.com/oGOviVEl/6/edit).

Comment: What would happen in the event of no timestamps in a line?

Comment: The RegEx will not match. My code just don't put the span tag when it not match.

Comment: What you wrote seems to work fine, but i've just revamped the entire console log viewer. i need to do this in php instead of javascript, any ideas?

Comment: I don't know php, but RegEx should work http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php .

Comment: Looks like `preg_match(string $pattern , string $text , array &$matches)` search `$pattern` regex in `$text`, writing the captured groups into `$matches` array.